# Is the Fast Fourier Transform associative?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, algorithms, fast-fourier-transform

For multiplying 2 polynomials, we can use the FFT:

$$IFFT(FFT(p(x)).FFT(q(x))) = p(x)*q(x)$$

Can I do

$$IFFT(FFT(p(x)).FFT(q(x)).FFT(r(x))) = p(x)*q(x)*r(x)$$
?

Where $.$ is coefficient-wise polynomial multiplication, and $*$ is simple polynomial multiplication.

If the above is true, then I could do

$$IFFT(p(x))*IFFT(q(x))*IFFT(r(x)) = IFFT(FFT(IFFT(p(x))).FFT(IFFT(q(x))).FFT(IFFT(r(x)))) = \ IFFT(p(x).q(x).r(x)) \implies FFT(IFFT(p(x))*IFFT(q(x))*IFFT(r(x))) = p(x).q(x).r(x)$$

I tried to use the relaion $FFT(IFFT(p(x))*IFFT(q(x))*IFFT(r(x))) = p(x).q(x).r(x)$ but I get garbage. Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, your reasoning is correct. You can certainly multiply 3 (or any number of) polynomials by Fourier transforming their coefficients, multiplying  coefficient-wise, and transforming back. Two notes though:

- Using the fourier->multiply->fourier trick computes the **periodic** convolution of two (or more) sequences of numbers. For polynomial-multiplication, you need a **non-periodic** convolution. In practice this means you need to add some padding to the inputs (i.e. leading zero coefficients). And the amount of padding needed increases, the more polynomials you want to multiply. My guess would be that this is your problem.
- Your notation can be improved: If $p$ is a polynomial, then $p(x)$ is a single number. So writing $FFT(p(x))$ is formally nonsensical. Also you should really write something like $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^\dagger$ or $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ instead of $FFT$ and $IFFT$, which looks quite jarring in a math context.

Comment: I was actually talking about the discrete FFT over rings, usually called NTT. It's generally used for multiplying polynomials and the transformation is a vector (or maybe we can view as another polynomial). These stuff still apply, right?

Comment: Yes, padding still works the same, and I would use the same symbol $\mathcal{F}$.  The things that are different with general rings (compared to complex numbers) are (1) arbitrary roots of unity may not exist in your ring (especially in a finite ring), which restricts your overall size to certain values (not a problem, there is no harm in having "too much" padding). and (2) the normalization of forward and backwards fourier might have to be adjusted, because the factor $1/\sqrt{n}$ might not make sense if the square root does not exist